# kuberneets pods images ErrImageNeverPull

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube, docker-registry

I have a docker image created user-service and tagged it to localhost:5001
I have a local registry running at PORT 5001

[image]

User-service pushed to local registry

[image]

and created pod using deploy_new.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: user-service
  labels:
    component: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web
      image: localhost:5001/user-service
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512Mi
          cpu: "1"
        requests:
          memory: 256Mi
          cpu: "0.2"
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 4006
          protocol: TCP
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /health/health
          port: 4006
        initialDelaySeconds: 3
        periodSeconds: 3
        failureThreshold: 2
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /health/health
          port: 4006
        initialDelaySeconds: 15
        periodSeconds: 10
```

But on describing pod
I get [image]

Questions :

1. What is ErrImageNeverPull image and how to fix it?
2. How to test liveliness and readiness probes?

Probe APIs
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**1. What is ErrImageNeverPull image and how to fix it?**

As the [`imagePullPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy)is set to `Never` the kubelet won't fetch images but look for what is present locally. The error means it could not found the image locally and it will not try to fetch it.

If the cluster can reach to your local docker registry, just change the `image: user-service` to `image: localhost:5000/user-service:latest`

If you are using minikube, check the [README](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/0c616a6b42b28a1aab8397f5a9061f8ebbd9f3d9/README.md#reusing-the-docker-daemon) to reuse your docker daemon so you can use your image without uploading it.

1. Do `eval $(minikube docker-env)` on each session you need to use it.
2. Build the image `docker build -t user-service .`
3. Add the image in your Pod manifest as `image: user-service`
4. make sure you have `imagePullPolicy: Never` for your container (which you already have)

**2. How to test liveliness and readiness probes?**

I suggest you try the examples form the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) they explain really good the difference between the two and the different types of probes you can configure.

You need first to make your pod running before checking liveness and readiness probes. But in your case they will succeed as soon as the Pod starts. Just describe it and see the events.

Comment: I have changed the image to 
localhost:5001/user-service but issue is persisting.

Comment: @RohitMittal, have you tried to reuse your docker daemon? that way minikube can see your builded image.

Comment: Sorry, If it is naive question but How can we do it?

Comment: @RohitMittal, here is the guide: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#:~:text=When%20using%20a%20container%20or,which%20speeds%20up%20local%20experiments.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to note. `eval $(minikube docker-env)` will fail silently if you are using a non-default `minikube` profile, leading to the observed behavior:

```bash
$ eval $(minikube docker-env)
$ minikube docker-env
  Profile "minikube" not found. Run "minikube profile list" to view all profiles.
  To start a cluster, run: "minikube start"
$
```

To address this re-run specifying the profile you are using:

```bash
$ eval $(minikube -p my-profile docker-env)
```